# Pass property value from TFS Build Definition to proj file

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild

I have a build definition set up in my TFS 2012 instance.  In this Build Definition I want to pass in a custom argument and access said argument in my .csproj file.  For example:

```
MSBuild Arguments: /p:MyFoo=1
```

In my .csproj file I want to do this:

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(MyFoo)' == '1' ">
```

Is this possible, or am I going about this incorrectly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is more than possible, it's very easy to do. Edit your build definition, under the process tab expand the "advanced" section and you will see a property called "MSbuild Arguments" add the argument in the format in the question. e.g. `/p:MyFoo=1`

e.g.

[image: adding msbuild arguments to TFS build definition]

You can also enter the arguments when you queue a build

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure this totally answers my question.  Are you saying I should be able to reference $(MyFoo) in my proj file?

Comment: @Matt yes, this will pass the Argument to MSbuild and $(MyFoo) will be available to all of the solutions / projects in the build.

Comment: You can view the msbuild activity inside your build process template it calls the msbuild to compile your solution/project - the MSBuild arguments are passed in addition to some already defined. If your value is something very static you can add it here so that you dont need to define this for every build definition. Upvoted

Comment: Turns out I was doing it the correct way, but had another issue in my build that was covering it up.  Thank you @JamesReed

Comment: @JamesReed I have been looking for this all day. Thanks!